# Set default value of a function

Tags: python-3.x, function, parameters, parameter-passing, default

I have to make a function which takes dataframe as one input and required columns as second input

```
def get_feature(df,cols=df.columns):
    . . .
    . . . 
    . . .
    return features
```

so here i want second parameter to be a list of columns which user can enter otherwise it should take all the columns of dataframe passed as parameter one as default, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
def get_feature(df, cols=None):
    if cols is None:
        cols = df.columns
    . . . 
    . . .
    return features
```